# Is using a list of unions a good practice?

Tags: java, c++, thrift

Union in thrift, by definition,

> provide a means to transport exactly one field of a possible set of
>   fields, just like union {} in C++. Consequently, union members are
>   implicitly considered optional (see requiredness).

My reasoning is that Union type does not exist anywhere except C++. Every time when I’m using this contract in Java, I need to split this collection in two, do some separate processing and merge two lists back again. 
The only usage of this type is for the single object when you trying to access some field, and if it wasn't set you taking the other one.

Is there any situation, where you should use collection of union objects instead of two separate collections?

Comment: C and C++ treats unions differently so you need to start by narrowing it down to one of those two. Does this library inherit union behavior from C or C++?

Comment: Even if a framework can be used from multiple languages, please don't spam with language tags. Only use the tags of the language you're actually programming in.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the idea was to get C++ and Thrift users answers. But thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @Lundin by definition that would be C++

Comment: Unions? No it is not a good practice to use unions. They can be helpful in some low level applications but its better to avoid them otherwise. Also if you need a union, say `union{int a; short b[2]}`, you can replace it with `short b[2]; int& a = *(int*)(void*)&b`. It isn't not as efficient but optimization should be able to resolve it... also, neither option is a good practice. In C++17 they added `std::variant` which is a better option for most cases.

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to translate C++ to Java. It's much stronger and translation is impossible in most of the cases. Current Java-like languages are made like memory don't exist. The reason is simplicity. Is much easier to learn such language. That's the reason they don't have unions. In Pascal there are unions too. Old languages don't pretend memory doesn't exist.
There are many use cases for using lists of unions. For example if you need to pass arguments to external function, you may create a Variant type, based on union and wrap the calls with multiple functions with const Variant & arguments.